# update a field in a row based on primary key in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have a table with fields ID(primary key),Name and Address. how can i update the Name corrosponding to a particular ID,without loading that row from the table and then updating it. I want to be able to just specify the new Name value along with the corrosponding ID so that it would be done automatically. I have enabled autocommit.
an example code would be nice,as I'm new to hibernate and don't wanna go deeply into createsession() and other things,just working on a project requiring quick and dirty solution :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using hql with your propertynames

```
session.createQuery("UPDATE Entity set name=@p1 WHERE id=@p2")
    .setParameter("p1", "newname")
    .setParameter("p2", id)
    .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks. By Entity,do you mean the Java class name,or do i have to create an object of the class and use the object's name?